# stringify in query-string module not working as expected in Jest tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, query-string, jestjs

I'm writing a unit test in Jest.

In the unit under test I am importing

```
import queryString from 'query-string'
```

and it is executing the code:

```
queryString.stringify(ids)
```

where ids is an array in the following format:

```
[{ id: '123' },{ id: '321' }]
```

This code works perfectly when running in my deployed webpage, but in a JEST test it gives the following output:

```
id=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&id=%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

whereas the same code in a browser gives:

```
id=123&id=321
```

As per the requisites of the [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) module, I am using a verison of node > 6.

I have also added:

```
/* jest commonjs */
```

to the top of my test file as query-string targets node.

Additionally I have tried setting various options in [stringify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string#stringify-object--options-) but to no avail.

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting different results in these different environments and how I can get my test to work? i.e. not render the string as "%5Bobject%20".

Sure, I could implement my own stringify method, but this library is built to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please define what the expected behavior would be?

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string), `stringify()` converts an object into a query. Since you are passing `ids`, an array of elements, there are different possible behaviors you may get.

Please note that, in javascript, an array is an object with numbers as keys, so `[ { id: '123' }, { id: '456' } ]` actually looks like `{ '0': { 'id': '123' }, '1': { 'id': '456' } }` (take a look at `Object.keys` of the array, you'll see it's `['0','1']`).

So, that being said, what queryString is doing is converting each pair key-value into `key=value`, where both `key` and `values` have been "stringified" (I'm assuming through the String constructor). Since the value is an object, it returns that things you're seeing (indeed, `String({})` is `[object Object]`. What I would expect (and I'm indeed getting) from the stringification of an array of objects is therefore something like `0=[object Object]&1=[object Object]` (with the square brackets converted to `%5B` and `%5D` and spaces to `%20`).

I don't really know where that `questionId` is coming from, so a little more context should be provided (e.g. showing the actual object being stringified could be useful) but, to get to the point, in order to avoid having your object be converted to `[object Object]` you should use a key extractor, that returns the value you actually want to be shown as value.

So, for example, if your array is as described above and the result you'd like to get is `0=123&1=456`, you would do something like:

```js
const ids = [ {id: '123'}, {id: '456'} ];
queryString.stringify(ids.map(v => v.id))
```

Instead, if the expected behavior is `id=123&id=456`, you need to convert the array to the object `{ id: ['123','456'] }`. You can do that with the following

```js
const ids = [ {id: '123'}, {id: '456'} ];
queryString.stringify({ id: ids.reduce( (c,v) => c.concat(v.id), []) })
```

So, you need to transform your original `ids` array into an object that is suitable for `stringify`.

Comment: The stringify method works perfectly in a browser but not in a node based Jest test. This answer doesnt address my problem.

Comment: I am honestly baffled by the fact that you are getting the expected behavior on the browser. The implementation of [encode()](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string/blob/master/index.js#L93) (used by `stringify()`) clearly makes use of `strict-uri-encode` which encodes objects the same way `encodeURIComponent()` and `String()` do. What happens if you run the code from the node command line? In any case, I would recommend using the extractor on `ids`; see the updated answer to get the expected result

Comment: I too am baffled by the fact that it works in the browser but not in Node, hence the question ;) Thanks for taking the time to answer this question and the suggestion to transform the array using reduce works great. I would have posted this question on the query-string repo page but they've closed it for comments!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs 
It has a working `qs.stringify`